# how to config a module bundler divide by folder with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I get the file structure like this

[before build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzes3.png)

I want to make it like this below with webpack

[after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJn64.png)

BTW, I also want to use ES6 `import` and `export` for the module loader,

such as in `nav.js`

```
class Nav extends Component {
  // react code here
}
export defalt Nav
```

and in `header.js`

```
import Nav from `nav/bundle`
// header react code 
// .......
export defalt Header
```

also need the bundle the `redux` and `react-route` npm package within the `node_module`

is it possible for webpack to do this stuff? some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough idea you could try to adapt:

```
{
  // generate these dynamically through JavaScript
  entry: {
    footer: <path to footer js>,
    ...
  },
  output: {
    path: './demo',
    filename: '[name]/bundle.js' // name maps to entry keys
  },
  ...
}
```